# apps script and google sheets, proper way to change range of named range?

Tags: google-apps-script, named-ranges

My core problem is I need to reference a changing range with a time based trigger. Since the function is executed from time I decided to use a named range but I'm running into issues with setRange().

Currently my code is similar to this:

```
var newRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, startCol, lenRow, lenCol);
SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getNamedRanges()
   .filter((range) => range.getName() == 'named_of_range')[0].setRange(newRange);
```

This works sometimes but other times newRange won't equal 'named_of_range' which is the named range I'd like to change. The height of the named range will be sometimes 1 more or 1 less than newRange. newRange is the correct range but the named range isn't updating properly.

Hopefully my explanation makes sense, if not I'd be happy to share more of my code. Thanks for any help or suggestions!

Comment: Can I ask you about the detail of `but I'm running into issues with setRange().`?

Comment: When I use setRange() the resulting namedRange doesn't equal the range that was provided in setRange(). In the actual sheet, the named range will sometimes be 1+ more than the provided range and other times its 1- less.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From `When I use setRange() the resulting namedRange doesn't equal the range that was provided in setRange(). In the actual sheet, the named range will sometimes be 1+ more than the provided range and other times its 1- less.`, in this case, can I ask you about the detail of your goal?

Comment: I'm having a hard time explaining how it works so I'm sorry if something doesn't make sense. I have a function that I want to execute from a time based trigger. The function needs to do two things: collect values from one range, write values to another specific range. I thought that a named range would be a good solution but was having issues with inconsistency. It would work sometimes but others the range wouldn't match the range I provided. I'm currently trying something else by writing the A1Notations of the specific ranges which I think will work

Comment: Sorry, just realized that my main issue is 'Exception: Service error: Spreadsheets' that happens when I use setValues() to on of the specific ranges. I was trying to figure out what that issue was from when I noticed the issue with named ranges but I'm getting thee same issue when I write the A1Notations to the sheet as well.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your posted answer, I understood that your issue was resolved. Is my understanding correct?

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work:

```
function changeNamedRangeName() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  let nr = ss.getNamedRanges();
  nr.forEach(r => {
    if(r.getName() == "Original") {
      r.setName("New Name");
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I tried in my code after changing the function to `changeNamedRangeName(rangeName, newRange)` and `setRange(newRange)` instead of `setName` but it still didn't work. I'm thinking there is some lag after the range is set but I could have another error in my program that I'm missing.

Comment: Are you sure you have the name correct?  There could possibly be spaces in the name that  you can't see at the end

Comment: Yeah it was correct, I was copy and pasting it. This did work for grabbing the named range but that turned out to not be the problem. Thank you for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure but think it was just an error in another part of my code. Sorry for asking before testing more of my own program and thank you both for helping me out.

The issue was that I was double upping an array with already existing items in the sheet while also adding to that same array. The length was used to determine the length of the named range which was making the issue. I'm still not sure why the range would sometimes be okay and other times not but at least it's working (for now).